# Cannot run files in Oracle oxygen

Tags: java, oracle

So I am in a personal study class in high school to prepare for college. Right now I am just starting the DS Malik Java textbook. I tried to set it up with Oracle Oxygen, but I cannot get it to work. I have only worked in Android studio prior to this and I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

I have tried the steps from this link -> [How can I avoid this Ant Build error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170959/how-can-i-avoid-this-ant-build-error)

I created a new project and imported it to the SRC folder like it said, I am not sure what it means by compliling, I think it means run and it still wont run. Now it just says it is unable to run.

I just am still lost. I cannot figure out how to create a project that I can run the files in for this textbook. IF any of you want to try it out before you reply since I know I am not being very forthcoming on details, there really aren't much I can say. But the source code is available online if you google it it will be there.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: This question is very broad. It would help to have a single specific example of what you have already tried.  What version of java are you working with? Are you trying to use ant to build your project?  Expecting us to google things to help you is not a good way to ask for help.

Comment: I'm very sorry I am super new to this I don't know what to provide for you, or in that matter what to search myself. I was just telling you if you wished to help you could look up the code and download the files and give it a try yourself. I get the same error as in the ant build article. I have never used this IDE and I am unfamiliar with it. In android studio I build files by connecting an android phone I have never had to mess with building projects. When I build it only has the ant to build with, so I guess yes I am trying to use ant to build my project.

Comment: If you are familiar with git and can push your code up to a public repo it might be easier to help you but this is falling outside of what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: Ok so I have been working in class more today, I sent this at the beginning and now I have figured out the files I copied from the folder run when not in the folders, but they are defined into folders for chapter management I can run programs now though so I'll look that up now.